# How to convert a NSString to a CGFloat in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I have been stuck for a couple of hours trying to get this to work. In my application I receive XML data, parse through it and create an image with buttons programmatically. However, when I try and convert Strings to CGFloats so that I can use them for the button coordinates it doesn't work. I have tried a few different tutorials and methods and nothing seems to work. You can see in the code below that I am trying it multiple ways. I know that the strings have the correct numbers in them, I just can't get it to convert. It comes back as Null.  Help! Thanks in advance

```
$CGFloat buttonViewXvalue = [tempXCorrVariable floatValue];
   CGFloat buttonViewYvalue = [tempYCorrVariable floatValue];
    buttonViewWidth = [tempWidthCorrVariable floatValue];
    buttonViewLength = [tempLengthCorrVariable floatValue];

    //The "buttonView" variables are Float Variables and the "temp" Variables are Strings.

    NSLog(@"Float X = %@", buttonViewXvalue); 
    NSLog(@"Float Y = %@", buttonViewYvalue);
    NSLog(@"Float Width = %@", buttonViewWidth);
    NSLog(@"Float Length = %@", buttonViewLength);
```

------------------------------------------ edit --------------------------------------------

Thanks to good responses I got it to work. Turns out it was simply a formatting issue with the NSLog. Here is the new code:

```
$CGFloat buttonViewXvalue = [tempXCorrVariable floatValue];
   CGFloat buttonViewYvalue = [tempYCorrVariable floatValue];
    buttonViewWidth = [tempWidthCorrVariable floatValue];
    buttonViewLength = [tempLengthCorrVariable floatValue]; 

    NSLog(@"Float X = %f", buttonViewXvalue);
    NSLog(@"Float Y = %f", buttonViewYvalue);
    NSLog(@"Float Width = %f", buttonViewWidth);
    NSLog(@"Float Length = %f", buttonViewLength);
```

For future reference for those who want to know how to convert a String to a float or CG float...simply follow this:

```
CGFloat yourFloatVariable = [stringThatYouWantToConvert floatValue];
```

Make sure that you use the exact word on the last part "floatValue." That isn't another variable or a value or anything, just put that in your code.

Comment: What do you see when you `NSLog(@"%@", tempXCorrVariable);`? Also, you're using the wrong format specifier for the floats: should be `NSLog(@"Float X = %lf", buttonViewXvalue);`. `%@` is only for objects.

Comment: @Josh Caswell you should leave an answer. OP simply is printing using the the wrong [string format specifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

Comment: @Joe: That's not the main problem -- if it's printing as `(null)`, that means the floats are `0.0`, which means there's something else wrong with the conversion. That's why I asked to see the printout of the `temp...` variables.

Comment: Well OP should post the string values stored in the variables as well. Log those with `%@`.

Comment: It was printing (null) but turns out that the NSLOG formatting was the problem. I simply corrected the formatting error and it is working with all the correct values. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the wrong format specifies: maybe your float values are right after all, but displaing it using the NSLog fails.

Use `NSLog(@"Float X = %f",buttonViewXvalue);` instead of `%@`.
Use only `%@` for NSObjects.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should take a moment to review the [string format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html):

```
%@     Object
%d, %i signed int
%u     unsigned int
%f     float/double

%x, %X hexadecimal int
%o     octal int
%zu    size_t
%p     pointer
%e     float/double (in scientific notation)
%g     float/double (as %f or %e, depending on value)
%s     C string (bytes)
%S     C string (unichar)
%.*s   Pascal string (requires two arguments, pass pstr[0] as the first, pstr+1 as the second)
%c     character
%C     unichar

%lld   long long
%llu   unsigned long long
%Lf    long double
```

When you use `%@` is send the message `address` to the `NSObject`. If you're using a `float`, then it isn't an `NSObject`, so errors will ensue.

To make your `NSLog` calls work, you have two options, of which I prefer the former:

```
NSLog(@"Float X = %f", myFloat); 
NSLog(@"Float X = %@", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat]);
```

The second is silly, but emphasizes the difference, I hope.

Comment: Yup you are absolutely correct. This was my problem. I corrected the format and it is working perfectly. I appreciate the in-depth answer!